# How to split group by result by year as a column into one row

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a Oracle table like below:

| ProductName | StorageTime | StorageCount | SupplyPrice | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2021-01-01 | 100 | 1.7 | 170 |
| Apple | 2022-01-01 | 200 | 1.7 | 340 |
| Orange | 2023-01-01 | 50 | 1.5 | 75 |

And I want to split data in the table to a excel like below:

| ProductName | 2021 StorageCount | 2021 Total | 2022 StorageCount | 2022 Total | 2023 StorageCount | 2023 Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 100 | 170 | 200 | 340 | 0 | 0 |
| Orange | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 75 |

The year column of excel is dynamic, It changes if the table changes.For example, The table have records from 1999~2023, The year columns shall as same as it.

I have tried SQL like below:

```
SELECT
    A.PRODUCTNAME,
    SUM( A.STORAGECOUNT ) AS STORAGECOUNT,
    SUM( A.STORAGECOUNT * SUPPLYPRICE ) AS TOTAL 
FROM
    T_STORAGE A 
GROUP BY
    A.PRODUCTNAME
```

I know that i can not put `STORAGETIME` in the `GROUP BY` conditions.How do i fix it :(

Comment: You're looking for `PIVOT`.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you! My problem has been fixed perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT PRODUCTNAME,
       SUM( CASE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM storagetime) WHEN 2021 THEN storagecount END )
         AS StorageCount_2021,
       SUM( CASE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM storagetime) WHEN 2021 THEN storagecount * supplyprice END )
         AS Total_2021,
       SUM( CASE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM storagetime) WHEN 2022 THEN storagecount END )
         AS StorageCount_2022,
       SUM( CASE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM storagetime) WHEN 2022 THEN storagecount * supplyprice END )
         AS Total_2022,
       SUM( CASE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM storagetime) WHEN 2023 THEN storagecount END )
         AS StorageCount_2023,
       SUM( CASE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM storagetime) WHEN 2023 THEN storagecount * supplyprice END )
         AS Total_2023
FROM   T_STORAGE
GROUP BY
       PRODUCTNAME
```